# I have just run my new node.js/express app on a new server which runs Ubuntu, how can i see my web app?

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, browser, express

I have just configured node.js, and express on a new linux server running Ubuntu. I have connected to the server via a console and done everything there. I have finally run my new web app made with express, how can i view it in my own computers browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: find out at which port the app is listening. The code you need will be something like `server.listen(1234)`, where 1234 is the port.

Step 2: find out your server's ip address. If you used ssh to connect to the server, use that ip or hostname. Eg. `ssh root@hostname`.

Step 3: in your browser navigate to `[hostname or ip]:[port]`

There could be other issues (express not handling the `/` route, firewall), but these are the basics.